# Swift ERROR : : Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I just started to learning Swift and,I'm trying to add a song into my code to play it when i press the button but that error shows up. how to fix this error?

```
var buttonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func btnWarning(sender: UIButton) {
    play()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func play() {
    let buttonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("warning", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let one = 1

    if one == 1 {
        buttonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: buttonAudioURL) //getting the error in this line
        buttonAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        buttonAudioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 9 question with the identical title in the "Related" section. Are you sure that your question hasn't been asked and answered before?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler correctly tells you that the initializer can throw an error as the [method declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error:) correctly states (e.g. when the `NSURL` does not exist):

```
init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) throws
```

Therefore you as the developer have to handle an eventually occuring error:

```
do {
    let buttonAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: buttonAudioURL)
} catch let error {
    print("error occured \(error)")
}
```

Alternatively you can tell the compiler that the call will actually always succeed via

```
let buttonAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: buttonAudioURL)
```

But that will cause your app to crash *if* the creation actually does not succeed - be careful. You only should use the second approach if you are trying to load app resources that **have** to be there.

Comment: thank you for your helps ! they both were correct but now i can't hear any sound and i have a file in there calling "warning.mp3"

I tried to put buttonAudioPlayer.play() in override func but not worked, also i tried to put it in my created fun and also didn't work, where should i have to put this?

Comment: @CemAtes If you have a second question, please post it as a separate one - this answer and question is about the potential error, not about the player not playing the file in the end :) Please accept an answer here, try to figure out a solution to your current problem and if you cannot find one, post a new question.

Comment: I just fixed somehow lol. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: buttonAudioURL)` may throw an exception. So you need to add exception handler code.

```
 do {
        try buttonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: buttonAudioURL)
    } catch {
        //handle exception here
    }
```